# Why viewstate value prints on page randomly?

Tags: c#, .net, postback

[image]

When a page gets the postback the viewstate value is printed on screen and stops there. It occurs randomly.

I have the webpage which gets postback from a popup window. This page displays the VIEWSTATE value sometimes on the page it self.

Comment: Where do you think all the data that has to persist between posts is stored?

Comment: I agree the ViewState stores the data between the postbacks. My question is why is it printing on the screen? There are UI controls on the page which are not displayed.  The attached screenshot is not from source code.. it is displayed on UI.

Comment: What do you mean by `UI controls`?  Are you talking about the ASP.NET controls?  Those are rendered to HTML so you would never see them by viewing page source.

Comment: I am not viewing source code. The view state value is displayed on the PAGE!! and stops rendering the rest of the page

Comment: Your page is double-encoding the ViewState input HTML. Please post your `.aspx` code which displays the `<form>` element. Also please post your *rendered* HTML of your `<form>` and `__VIEWSTATE` input (but please truncate the `value=""` attribute).

Comment: My guess is that the content-type header is wrong, e.g. text/plain or just outright missing.  Do you have any code that monkeys with the headers?

Comment: Sometimes __EVENTVALIDATION gets printed instead of VIEWSTATE... It happens only on few machines..